# How to debug cursor.execute (psycopg2) is NoneType

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I try to run SQL against my postgres db,

connection object I got through

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password='mysecretpassword'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
```

seems to be OK

```
result = cursor.execute(
"""
select 
* 
from 
planet_osm_point limit 10
""")
```

Result is Nonetype, so must be something wrong ?

What have I done wrong ? How could I debug this ?

Comment: Do you have data on `planet_osm_point` table?

Comment: yes, query success through pgAdmin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` only executes the query, it does not fetch any data. In order to receive data, you will need to call `cursor.fetchall()` or `cursor.fetchone()`.

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "host = 'localhost' port = '5432' dbname = 'postgres' user = 'postgres' password = 'mysecretpassword'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor.execute(
""" 
select 
* 
from 
planet_osm_point limit 10
""")

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Call fetchall() or fetchone() on the CURSOR, not the result of the execute(). The answer does say this, but I still missed it.